# 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
def g_view(request):
    header_category = Category.objects.all()
    m = Type1.objects.all()
    r=Type2.objects.all()
    g=Type3.objects.all()
    from itertools import chain
    orders=list(sorted(chain(m,r,g),key=lambda objects:objects.start))

    mquery = request.GET.get('m')
    if mquery:
        orders = orders.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=mquery) |
            Q(game__name__icontains=mquery) |
            Q(teams__name__icontains=mquery)).distinct()
```

(Type is abstract and type1 type2 type3 are inherited classes)

I got this error 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically when you [**`chain`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) multiple queryset, you loose the ability of queryset. After chaining, they become part of an iterator. And you can access the values of iterator by iterating it or calling `list` explicitly. You need to do the query before chaining the queryset.

```
query = Q(name__icontains=mquery) |
        Q(game__name__icontains=mquery) |
        Q(teams__name__icontains=mquery)

m = Type1.objects.filter(query).distinct()
r = Type2.objects.filter(query).distinct()
g = Type3.objects.filter(query).distinct()


orders=list(sorted(chain(m,r,g),key=lambda objects:objects.start))
```